# Which API to automatically know total page views of pages containing specific strings in url?

Tags: google-analytics-api

Can anyone please tell me what API should be used to know total page views and unique page views of pages containing specific strings in url? For example: total page views and unique page views of all pages containing "default" in url, total page views and unique page views of all pages containing "step" in url etc.

We do it manually to generate monthly report. Now we are planning to develop an automated system where we will give required strings and date range as inputs and we will get our monthly reports as output.

Comment: Welcome to stack please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  After that try this https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use [Core Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/).

Here is a sample query that would get you all pages containing **step** and the number of pageviews:

> https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3A12345&start-date=2015-05-01&end-date=2015-06-08&metrics=ga%3Apageviews&dimensions=ga%3ApagePath&sort=-ga%3Apageviews&filters=ga%3APagePath%3D%40step